# Initializing a variable with a function that takes that variable as an argument

Tags: c++

I was recently reviewing some code and I came across something that I was confused about. Say I have a functions, `int getNewNumber(int num, int dir)`, implemented like this:

```
int getNewNumber(int num, int dir) {
    int newNum = num;
    if(dir == 1) {
        newNum++;
    } else {
        newNum--;
    }
    return newNum;
}
```

Now, when calling the function, I have something like this:

```
int number = getNewNumber(number, 1);
```

Is it initialized to 0 before being passed into newNum? I'm confused about how you can use the variable as an argument when it's being initialized.

Comment: Is there another variable with the same name in an outer scope?

Comment: That code should not compile as C++ code - your function needs a return type.

Comment: You are reading an uninitialized variable which is at least unspecified behavior.

Comment: @nwp Undefined in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza is this defined in C? The file is a .cpp file but it's implemented on an embedded system so I think it's actually C code. I may have tagged it incorrectly.

Comment: @compsciguy IIRC, in C it is either unspecified, or undefined, depending on the implementation.

Comment: Why do you even want to use the variable as the argument if its value is unknown? Why don't do `0` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it initialized to 0 before being passed into newNum?

Maybe. It depends on context. If the variable is a global static, then it is zero initialized before dynamic initialization.

If it is an automatic variable, then the value passed into `getNewNumber` is indeterminate and using that value has undefined behaviour. A decent compiler will warn you.

> I'm confused about how you can use the variable as an argument when it's being initialized.

If the variable wasn't initialized statically, then you can't use its value in its own initialization in a way that would have defined behaviour.

If the variable was zero initialized before dynamic initialization, then you can use the value, but you might as well use literal zero, and that would be clearer to the reader of the program. I don't think there is any useful way to use the value of a variable in its own initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I really think it depends on the compiler. In general I'd call it unsafe - in the best case you'll get a a value, that has the same type, or can be converted to this type. In the worst case - the program will simply crash.